# A field with type GameObject in a class which inherits from ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Sphere_SO", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Sphere")]
public class Sphere_SO : ScriptableObject
{
    public int FieldInteger;
    public GameObject FieldGameObject;
}
```

In file .asset it is easy to initialize an integer, but how to initialize the GameObject? File .asset and integers do not depend on scene, GameObject is on one scene. Is it possible to have a value in that field?

Comment: if that gameobject is prefab , maybe can do it.

Comment: what really purpose to do ? , why you need use ScriptableObject , for what ?